# Method Parameters and ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

Alright so I am working on a small program in which I have a method which accesses an Arraylist.

So:

`public void setGroups(int groupA, int groupB, ArrayList< String > groups)`

then I have my Arraylist in the body of my main method:

`ArrayList groupSets = new ArrayList< String >(
     Arrays.asList("group1", "group2" ));`

So my question is, how do I call this code in my main method? My issue is with the arraylist part. Also these ints of groupA/B, I will be using these to pull elements out of the ArrayList.

So it would be like?:

`playGame(0, 1, ArrayList< String > groupSets);`

Except I know that the arraylist part is wrong and I am unsure if the ints are right or wrong as well, they seem right but I could be completely off. Please any help?!

Comment: Why not make that method return an Arraylist? Having a setter method with side effects seems to be a bad design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration and call are different, so your question is a bit confusing.

The call should not include any type information:

```
setGroups(groupA, groupB, groups);
```

Comment: Alright so when I format my call in this fashion: setGroups(0, 1, groups); it throws an error stating "non-static method setGroups(int, int, ArrayList<String>) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Create an instance of the class that implements that method.

Answer (score 0):

Its just

```
ArrayList<String> groupSets = new ArrayList<String>(); 
playGame(0, 1, groupSets);
```

Answer (score 0):

In agreement with both of the partial answers above, let's see if we can make this  comprehensive:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> groupSets = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("group1", "group2"));
        GroupStuff gs = new GroupStuff();
        gs.setGroups(0,1,groupSets);
    }

    public void setGroups(int groupA, int groupB, List<String> groups) {    
        //Do whatever you do here...
    }
}
```

And....

```
playGame(0, 1, ArrayList< String > groupSets);
```

should be

```
playGame(0, 1, groupSets);
```